# How to filter ModX Revolution GalleryAlbums by tags / year

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

How is it possible, to group or at least grab albums by year or tag?
E.g.:

```
2014
- Album 1
- Album 2

2013
- Album 3
```

I've studied the [manual](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/gallery) but unfortunately without finding any hints ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new album (called 2014) and place the other albums inside (Album 1, Album 2, etc.)

You can drag and drop albums into your 2014 folder or just right click it to create new subfolders.